# What does Windows' refresh right click context menu command do?

Tags: windows, user-interface, refresh

The title should be self explanatory enough.
This "refresh" has existed since before Windows XP days.
What does it do exactly?

Answer (score 2):

It will reload the content of the directory.

Lets say, you remove files using a script and you view that folder with explorer, explorer was not the one executing that remove command, and as such explorer may not realize that the files were removed.

Nowadays, there are monitors that will periodically check the content of the folder you're viewing, and if a changes was detected, the refresh action is automatically called, but sometimes this monitor does not detect the change, and while the folder has changed, explorer just does not show you.

For these instances, you can hit F5, or right-click and select Refresh, to refresh the content of the folder you're viewing.

It is effectively the same as navigating to the previous map, and then back into that map, except its faster to execute, especially if you can just press F5.

The refresh command is a universal command though. Many programs feature this. In webbrowsers, this reloads the webpage for example, and on an FTP client, this would reload the content of the folder you're viewing.

Basically, any program that can externally modify the content you're viewing, almost always has a refresh function that you can manually trigger, often using the F5 key.